# How do I get JUnit tests to run with Gradle project?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, junit, build.gradle

**Question**

How do I run JUnit unit tests in a Java Gradle project?

**Explanation**

I have a Java Gradle project. It's using Vert.x, but right now I'm just trying to start off with the basics (JUnit) before I use Vert.x Unit. I want to start writing unit tests for my project. I'm a super-beginner when it comes to unit tests.

I cannot figure out how to run my unit tests. I have a directory in my project `src/test/java`, and in that directory I have a package `com.mycompany.myproject.verticle`. Inside of that package, I have a class:

```
package com.mycompany.myproject.verticle;

import org.junit.test;

public class VerticleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testTest() {
        System.out.println("TESTING ::::::::");
    }
}
```

In my `build.gradle` file, I added the following:

```
testCompile('junit:junit:4.13')
...
sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src/test/java"]
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my terminal, while in the root of the project, I run:

```
./gradlew test
```

My test does not print anything out. I don't see anything in the console output that indicates that a test was run.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried changing the `srcDirs` value to encompass the entire directory (`src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject`) just to get it to work, even though I'm sure in the future I will have different unit tests in different packages. I've tried changing the `srcDirs` value to just `.`, and then `/`. None of those seemed to work.

I've tried to just build my project with `./gradlew clean build`, to see if that would pick my tests up, but that did not work.

I've tried changing `testCompile(...)` to `testImplementation(...)`. That did not work.

Comment: what is the output of your `./graldew test` command?  by default in Gradle you won't have test execution logs ,  but you can enable logging by configuring test task like : `test {    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true }`

Comment: you can also increase log level when executing Gradle, which will display output of your unit test:  `./gradlew test -i`

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to run tests is to use command for running tests in separated modules, and you have to do clean command first, to get clean state, for example:

```
./gradlew clean lib:testDebugUnitTest -i
```

In that case module name is "lib" - change it to your name of module.
If you have tests in app - name it as **app:testDebugUnitTest**

**Argument **-i****:

- will only get you more info about everything running in behind.